# subdomain two separate websites in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, subdomain

I would like your guidance on this.

I'm trying to build a website that has two "players" (which, I assume can be translated to "roles"?). One player is "consumer" and the second player is "supplier".
Both are interacting through mutual (sql server) database.
Now I would like to have totally separate systems each player, with totally different authentication mechanisms.
However, I would like to have the consumers system as sub-domain of the main domain, i.e., I would like to have the consumer system under 'mydomain.com', and the suppliers system under 'supplier.mydomain.com'.
However, I can't figure out how to technically do this? Can I create another web project in my solution, call it 'suppliers' and let it include all the features of the suppliers system?
Or should I create separate controllers for the suppliers features inside the main project?

The first option sounds most "clean" to me, however, how can I route the user from the main (the consumers) website to the suppliers website based on the subdomain?

If I choose the second option, how can I make sure that user which authenticated as customer will not be able to perform as supplier?

This is probably very common task to do, any good tutorial or example for this?

Comment: Given you want clear separation, I'd probably suggest building and deploying these as two separate applications. These would share some common code but be managed as separate projects. Then you can have two separate IIS applications mapped to your different domains as well as clear authentication separation and management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will create two separate IIS applications - one for your consumers and another for your suppliers.

You will then set the host headers on each to your required domain and subdomain. IIS will then take care of routing URLs to your separate applications. Instructions for setting IIS host headers here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195.aspx

As for managing application code, given you want complete separation I would suggest creating three Visual Studio projects:

1. Web application for consumers
2. Web application for suppliers
3. Class library of shared code - database logic etc

You are then able to develop and deploy each web application independently.

In terms of tutorials, there is quite a lot available, here are a few which will help you:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150710/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122403-1.aspx
- https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/partitioning-your-code-base-through-.net-assemblies-and-visual-studio-projects/
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207101/managing-multiple-projects-that-share-code-customization

Answer (score 0):

for this problem, so use "Area" = 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Areas provide mapping and functionality for different application paths, I'm not sure they handle sub-domains out of the box though do they? If so, might be worthwhile expanding your answer...